# Question re deriving formula for the integer sequence presented as square table read by rows

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

The OEIS A035002 infinite integer sequence is presented as a square table being read by rows.
I found that the generalized ordinary generating function (ogf) for the sequences, formed by the columns of above mentioned table, is described as follows:

ogf for table's column "j"

**$$(x - 1)^j / (2*x - 1)^j$$** for j=1;

**$$((3*x - 2)^{j-2}*(x - 1)^2) / (2*x-1)^j$$** for j>1.

Is it possible to derive formula and/or generating function describing integer sequence A035002 as a whole on the basis of above presented generalized ordinary generating function (ogf) for the sequences formed by the columns?

As Michael Somos commented below:
"The array is symmetric. That is, the nth row is the same as the nth column."

Comment: The array is symmetric. That is, the nth row is the same as the nth column.

Comment: @Somos - thanks for your comment!  Any thoughts re my question?

Comment: @Somos Also it appears that for A035001 lgdegf is:
16-32*a(n)+24*a(n)^2-8*a(n)^3+a(n)^4 but I don't know how to prove or disprove it. Could you please help?

Comment: Please ask a new different question for help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the power series expansions of the rows it is possible
to find binomial summations for the array values. More precisely,
the generating function for the array is

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty T(n,m) x^n y^m =
 \frac{ (1-x)(1-y) } { 1 - 2x - 2y + 3xy }. $$

Note that $\,T(n,m) = T(m,n)\,$ for all $\,n,m.\,$
Some special cases include:

$\, T(n, m) = 0\,$ if $\, n<0,m<0.\,$  $\,T(0, 0) = 1,
T(n,0) = 2^{n-1}, T(0, m) = 2^{m-1}\,$.

Otherwise, $\,n>0,m>0.\,$ The binomial summation expression is

$$ T(n,m) = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \sum_{k=0}^2
   2^i 2^{n-1 - (m-i-k)} {\binom  {m-1} {i}}
{\binom  {2} {k}} {\binom  {n-1} {m-i-k}}. $$

This expression was derived directly from the row or column generating functions

$$ R_1(x) := 1 + \frac{x}{1-2x},\;\; R_j(x) :=
 \Big(1 + \frac{x}{1-2x}\Big)^2
 \Big(2 + \frac{x}{1-2x}\Big)^{j-2}. $$

---

Note that, unfortunately, there are **two** conventions used in
[OEIS A035002](https://oeis.org/A035002).
One where $\,n,m\ge 0\,$ and the other where $\,n,m > 0.\,$